# Google Cloud Compute Engine VMs with Alpine Linux

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, alpine

How to create GCE image with [Alpine Linux](https://alpinelinux.org) that can be used to create GCE VMs?

Answer (score 1):

In order to work properly in GCE and interact with the execution environment, a guest OS should be pre-configured appropriately. Usually it is done by Google or Linux vendors in the process of preparing the system image.

[Compute Engine > Doc > Guest environment > Supported operating systems](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/guest-environment#supported-os)

[Compute Engine > Doc > Guest environment > The Linux guest environment](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/guest-environment#linux)

Since Alpine Linux is not listed among either the [Public images](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#os-compute-support) provided by Google or the [Community supported images](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#community_supported_images), it is up-to-you how to prepare the Alpine Linux to run in GCE.

There is an instruction out there you can follow:

[Setting up Alpine Linux in Google Cloud Platform ( GCP )](https://riedstra.dev/2019/09/alpine-gcp)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I was hoping that there are some automation that I can use to create Alpine GCE image, i.e. - pass to it Alpine version and it produces GCE-compatible image.

Comment: Now your link to the tutorial is dead.

Comment: It seems the Alpine Linux instruction was migrated. The link is updated now.